# checking if two lists are equal in Maple

Tags: list, equality, maple

I've got the following lists :

list1:=[1, 5, 14, 30, 55, 91, 140, 204, 285, 385, 506, 650, 819, 1015,

1240, 1496, 1785, 2109, 2470, 2870]
list2:=[1, 5, 14, 30, 55, 91, 140, 204, 285, 385, 506, 650, 819, 1015,

1240, 1496, 1785, 2109, 2470, 2870]

each generated by a procedure I defined. I need to verify that they are equal, which is the case. However, when I tried to use the evalb function as well as a flag that I was updating during a loop, in both cases, I got 'false' as  the answer along with the error message:

"error, final value in a for loop must be numeric or a character"

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to post some code.  As saforrest says, Maple automatically reduces equal lists to the same object.  The error you are getting is about something else.

Answer (score 1):

Maple will automatically resolve multiple copies of lists with identical entries to the same object.  So to test equality, you don't even need to traverse the lists programmatically.  You can just do:

```
evalb(list1=list2);
```

If however you'd like to do a more sophisticated comparison, you can use the [verify](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=verify) command. For example, this will verify that the first list has the second list as a sublist:

```
verify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], superlist);
```

Calling verify with no second argument is equivalent to the first evalb test, e.g.:

```
verify(list1, list2);
```